# Executing particular tests under ruby test framework

Tags: ruby

I have a set of test cases under ruby test framework 1.8.7

Lets say i have a ruby file named check.rb which contains differents tests like 
test_a_check, test_b_check and test_c_check.

Now when i run the file ruby check.rb, all the test cases will be executed.

My part of the question is,
I want to pass a new parameter to the script while running, say ruby check.rb --sunset

based on the sunset parameter i want my script to execute only test_a_check and test_b_check and not the test_c_check.

By default, if i run the script all the tests should be excuted but when the --sunset parameter is passed only two of three tests should be executed.

is there are way i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using minitest you can specify the method via

```
ruby check --name test_method_name
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a common testing framework, then look into it's manual, but
If it's your personal testing script, then just look in ARGV:

```
test_a_check
test_b_check
test_c_check if ARGV[0] != '--sunset'
```